# Share data among all instances of the Class Java

Tags: java, class

I have class Friends and I need data that enumerates (associates with a number) the first names of three friends, classmates or coworkers. I need to make it so that this name data will be shared among all instances of the class.

```
public class Friends {

    public String friends[] = {"John", "Andrew", "Pitt"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Friends friends1 = new Friends();
        Friends friends2 = new Friends();
        Friends friends3 = new Friends();
    }
}
```

How to share name data among all instances?

Comment: This is what static variables are for

Comment: but i cannot call static variable with an instance

Comment: Yes, static variables can be used with an instance.  However, in the use-case you've described that you're doing makes no sense.  A better way would be for Friend to contain a `Set` of friends.  Then you would do something like `friend.addFriend(other)` and then `other.addFriend(friend)`